# Unable to tokio::run a boxed Future because the trait bound Send is not satisfied

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a function that should optionally run a future or do nothing, depending on parameters. I tried putting a `Box` around the two futures that will be returned, a `tokio::prelude::future::Done<Item=(), Error=()>` that immediately resolves to `Ok(())`, and a `tokio::timer::Delay` that I'm using `and_then` and `map_err` to turn both the `Item` and `Error` to `()`. This doesn't seem to work for me when I try to run the futures with `tokio::run`.

```
extern crate tokio;

use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use tokio::prelude::*;
use tokio::timer;

fn main() {
    tokio::run(foo(12));
}

fn foo(x: i32) -> Box<Future<Item = (), Error = ()>> {
    if x == 0 {
        Box::new(
            timer::Delay::new(Instant::now() + Duration::from_secs(5))
                .and_then(|_| Ok(()))
                .map_err(|_| ()),
        )
    } else {
        Box::new(future::result(Ok(())))
    }
}
```

This fails to compile with the following error message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `tokio::prelude::Future<Error=(), Item=()>: std::marker::Send` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:8:5
  |
8 |     tokio::run(foo(12));
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^ `tokio::prelude::Future<Error=(), Item=()>` cannot be sent between threads safely
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `tokio::prelude::Future<Error=(), Item=()>`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::ptr::Unique<tokio::prelude::Future<Error=(), Item=()>>`
  = note: required because it appears within the type `std::boxed::Box<tokio::prelude::Future<Error=(), Item=()>>`
  = note: required by `tokio::run`
```

It appears that `Box<Future...>` does not implement `Send`, which doesn't make sense to me. Since the `Future` types that I'm returning both implement `Send`, it seems to me that the `Box` should, since `impl Send for Box<T> where T: Send` is an auto implement in the stdlib. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I realized that I need to specify in the return type to `Foo` that the future is `Send`. This compiles:

```
extern crate tokio;

use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use tokio::prelude::*;
use tokio::timer;

fn main() {
    tokio::run(foo(12));
}

fn foo(x: i32) -> Box<Future<Item = (), Error = ()> + Send> { // note the + Send at the end of this line
    if x == 0 {
        Box::new(
            timer::Delay::new(Instant::now() + Duration::from_secs(5))
                .and_then(|_| Ok(()))
                .map_err(|_| ()),
        )
    } else {
        Box::new(future::result(Ok(())))
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, in this case you could just use [impl trait and `Either`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7d8030b979eaa2cdb42def7704124479&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015).

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster! That's exactly what I wanted. That's much better than boxing.