# How do I specify that any type satisfying a given first trait under certain trait bounds must also implicitly satisfy a second trait?

Tags: rust, traits, rust-tokio

I have a similar situation as [Unable to tokio::run a boxed Future because the trait bound Send is not satisfied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51485410/unable-to-tokiorun-a-boxed-future-because-the-trait-bound-send-is-not-satisfie)): I want to use `tokio::run` on types of `Box<T: Future ...>` where `T` does not implement `Send`.

My situation is different in that I didn't write the method which returns my `Box`, and so can't change its method signature. It performs a web request and returns this boxed future:

```
pub fn get_resource(&self,) -> Box<Future<Item = RestStruct, Error = Error<serde_json::Value>>>
```

Note the lack of `Send`.

Per the [Tokio documentation](https://tokio.rs/docs/going-deeper/returning/#tk-docs-nav), I need to implement `Send` on my boxed type, which isn't automatic even if the future's associated types are `Send`:

> Astute readers may notice the explicit `Send` trait notation within the `Box` definition. The notation is added because `Future` is not explicitly `Send` by default; this causes problems later when trying to pass this future or one of its derivatives into `tokio::run`.

I'm having trouble figuring out an appropriately concise way to do this. It seems like something along these lines should work:

```
impl<T, I, E> Send for T
where
    T: Future<Item = I, Error = E>,
    I: Send,
    E: Send,
{
}
```

I get a number of surprising errors. I'll detail them below, but my question can be generally phrased, how do I specify: **any type satisfying a given first trait under certain trait bounds must also implicitly satisfy a second trait**?

---

The errors my solution produced:

> the trait `std::marker::Send` requires an `unsafe impl` declaration

I think I understand that one based on the documentation about `Send`, though to clarify: this would indeed constitute a "properly implemented `Send`" as [described there](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/send-and-sync.html), because the associated types are `Send`?

> type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g., `MyStruct<T>`)

I understand this to be related to the [newtype workaround as described in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html), which would really get in the way of doing what I want to do if so. Does this mean I can't accomplish what I want? Is there something like a type alias for bounded traits that would get around this?

> conflicting implementations of trait `std::marker::Send` for type `&_`

That one, I don't understand at all. `&_` is far broader a type than the constrained one I tried to specify using all those `where` bounds; I would not expect `&_` to be `Future<Item = I: Send, Error = E: Send>`.

Comment: *I didn't write the method which returns my `Box`* — then you are basically out of luck. Your question is essentially the same as saying "I have a type that doesn't implement `Display`; how do I lie to the compiler and make it believe the type does?". You don't have any guarantees that the returned type *can* be sent between threads, which very well might mean that it **cannot**.

Comment: Additionally, your hypothetical blanket implementation cannot work and for good reason. Just I could easily have `struct IsNotSend(...); impl Future for IsNotSend { Item = i32, Error = () }`. Both `Item` and `Error` are `Send`, but the struct itself is not.

Comment: I see, that helps me understand where i was making a false conclusion, because even if `Item` and `Error` are `Send` types, there's no reason non-send elements could not also exist in the containing concrete type. In my case, the returned implementer of `Future` coincidentally has no other data contents, but this can't be known based on the signatures. Thank you.